# Dictionaries in a if statement arent working

Tags: python, dictionary

When I print my Clients dictionary keys using option 2, it shows up as `[]` even when I've already added a client. Can anyone help me understand what is going wrong?

```
def main():
    import sys
    Clients = {}

    choice = input(" Click 1 to add another client\n Click 2 to Check a Clients Balance\n Click 3 to change a Clients Balance ")

    if choice == "1":
            name = input('Add a Client\'s name : ')
            Clients.update({name.rstrip("\n"):0})
            print(name)
            print(Clients.keys())
            main()
    elif choice == "2":
            print(Clients.keys())
            main()
    elif choice == "3":
            print('Do it later')
            main()
    else:
            print('Please choose again')
            main()

main()
```

Comment: Because you clearly tell it to do so?  `print(Clients.keys())`.

Comment: You should not be trying to loop your program by calling `main` recursively. Each recursive call creates a new `Clients` dictionary.

Comment: Why do you make all those recursive calls to `main`?  A simple `while` loop would take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `main` again and again, using a new dictionary each time, this is called recursion. Here, you should use a while loop.

```
def main():
    clients = {}
    while True:
        choice = input("Click 1 to add another client\n Click 2 to Check a Clients Balance\n Click 3 to change a Clients Balance ")

        if choice == "1":
            name = input("Add a Client's name : ")
            clients[name.rstrip()] = 0
            print(name)
            print(clients.keys())
        elif choice == "2":
            print(clients.keys())
        elif choice == "3":
            print('Do it later')
        else:
            print('Please choose again')

main()
```

Comment: @malik-ware In addition to the fact that a while loop is more appropriate for this use case, it is critical that the `clients` dictionary is defined outside of the loop, otherwise you would run into the same problem.